# Change a MessageBox default button?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have:

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to delete?", 
                    "", 
                    MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
```

I tried adding:

```
MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2

if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to delete?", 
                    "", 
                    MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2,
                    MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
```

The C# compiler does not like:

```
MessageBoxDefaultButton
```

To clarify "The C# compiler does not like", the word MessageBoxDefaultButton stays the color black. It does not change to blue.
I am using C# 2013.

Comment: What do you mean by `The C# compiler does not like`? Actually including any errors will help people help you.

Comment: Are you missing an import, specifically: `using System.Windows.Forms;`?

Comment: Incidentally, have you tried actually looking at the parameter list for the various overloads of `MessageBox.Show Method`?

Comment: There is no [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes `MessageBoxDefaultButton` as a third argument.

Comment: As a guess, you might be after this one: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctd56yay(v=vs.110).aspx But you should do all of this research yourself.

Comment: The default button parameter is in wrong place
`MessageBox.Show(IWin32Window, String, String, MessageBoxButtons, MessageBoxIcon, MessageBoxDefaultButton)`

Comment: To clarify "The C# compiler does not like", the word MessageBoxDefaultButton stays the color black.   It does not change to blue.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer, thanks to Sinatr

```
if(MessageBox.Show ("Do you want to delete this page?",
                    "", 
                    MessageBoxButton.YesNo, 
                    MessageBoxImage.Question, 
                    MessageBoxResult.No) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
```